# Error "No module named 'numpy.core._ufunc_config'" while importing matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am receiving the error "No module named 'numpy.core._ufunc_config'" while importing matplotlib.pyplot .
I tried the following already

```
pip install --upgrade pip #upgrading pip to latest version
pip install --upgrade matplotlib #upgrading matplotlib to latest version
```

But it does not seem to work.
Complete error is as follows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a0d2faabd9e9> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    136 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    137 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 138 from . import cbook, rcsetup
    139 from matplotlib.cbook import (
    140     MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in <module>
     29 from weakref import WeakMethod
     30 
---> 31 import numpy as np
     32 
     33 import matplotlib

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     93 from . import numerictypes as nt
     94 multiarray.set_typeDict(nt.sctypeDict)
---> 95 from . import numeric
     96 from .numeric import *
     97 from . import fromnumeric

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in <module>
     33 from ._exceptions import TooHardError, AxisError
     34 from ._asarray import asarray, asanyarray
---> 35 from ._ufunc_config import errstate
     36 
     37 bitwise_not = invert

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._ufunc_config'
```

Comment: Looks like your numpy install is broken.

Comment: how do i fix it?

Comment: Reinstalling numpy I'd say.